# PHP OOP: How to get database values and return all of them

Tags: php, database, function, return, echo

I am trying to get all the results from the database and return them to the screen, the problem is once i "echo" the value's they all show up, but when I use "return" only 1 shows up.

I can't use echo because my application is build on a way it puts html into functions so i can fill objects and then fill the content of my page.

Here is my code.

```
public function read() {
    $query = "SELECT id, title, description, datetime FROM seminar";
    $result = $this->getDb()->query($query);

    while(($row = $result->fetchObject()) !== false) {
        foreach($row as $value) {
        return $row->title;
        //$this->setDescription($row->description);
        //$this->setDatetime($row->datetime);
        }
    } 
}
```

Now I am wondering how to get all value's on the screen instead of just the one it is showing now.

```
public function setSeminar($sem_obj) {
    $this->sem_obj = $sem_obj;
}

public function render() {
    $this->content = '
        On this page you can see all items.
    ';
    $this->content .= $this->sem_obj->getTitle();
    $this->content .= $this->sem_obj->getDescription();
    $this->content .= $this->sem_obj->getDatetime();
    //$this->content .= $this->text1->showSeminairs();
    return $this->content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use an array.. push the databaseobjects and return that

```
$tempArray=array();
while(($row = $result->fetchObject()) !== false) {

      $tempArray['title']=$row->title;
     $tempArray['description']=$row->description;
      return $tempArray;

}
```

Comment: The functions are in different classes does that matter?

Comment: that shouldnot.. if you are calling thr class and function corectly

Comment: I tried your example like this: public function read() {
        $query = "SELECT id, title, description, datetime FROM seminar";
        $result = $this->getDb()->query($query);
        $values = array();
        while(($row = $result->fetchObject()) !== false) {
            //foreach($row as $values) {
                $values['title'] = $row->title;
                return $values;
            //$this->setDescription($row->description);
            //$this->setDatetime($row->datetime);
            //}
        } 
    } but Im not sure how to fill in in the render function

Answer (score 0):

```
public function read() {
    $query = "SELECT id, title, description, datetime FROM seminar";
    $result = $this->getDb()->query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

In the caller function, put while loop and process the values.

Comment: The functions are in different classes does that matter?

Comment: That is not a problem. It will return to the function wherever you are calling from